# Add custom product after x items in shop loop Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to add a custom product by ID after X items in the Woocommerce shop loop. I am using this code right now:

```js
function add_item_after_x_shop()
{
  global $wp_query;
  if ($wp_query->current_post == 2 && $wp_query->current_post != 0 && is_shop()) {
    echo do_shortcode('[product id="11"]');
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_shop_loop', 'add_item_after_x_shop');
```

And it will add a product with `ID = 11` in the 3rd position. But the problem is that this shortcode creates a new row and a new line. I want to add this item inside the collection, not create a new collection. Any help?